# Google fusion table math formula

Tags: angularjs, google-fusion-tables

How to calculate and update a `new column` from `existing columns` in `google fusion table`.

Please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Using normal formulas like in Excel, we can create a new formula column and we have to write our own formula.

> Eg. `a+b+c` where `a,b,c` are column names, if you have space in column name use single quote.

Please check the below link for more details - https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/178196?hl=en